# Exact definition of boundedness in a Frechet space : bounded with respect to "each" seminorm?

Tags: general-topology, functional-analysis

Let $V$ be a Frechet space with the seminorms given by $\lVert \cdot \rVert_n$ for $n=1,2,3, \cdots$.

Then, in the Wikipedia https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bounded_set_(topological_vector_space), it is stated that a set $B \subset V$ is bounded if it is bounded with respect to all $\lVert \cdot \rVert_n$.

Does it mean

1. $\lVert x \rVert_n \leq C_n$ for all $x \in B$ and each $n$ or
2. $\lVert x \rVert_n \leq C$ for all $x \in B$ and all $n$?

where $C_n$'s and $C$ are some positive constants. The former depends on $n$ while the latter doesn't.

Wikipedia is somewhat obscure in stating the property, so I am confused. Certainly, the second condition is much stronger than the first condition, but which one exactly corresponds to boundedness in a Frechet space?

Could anyone please clarify?

Comment: Do you have a real textbook? Wikipedia is not a reliable source for mathematics.

Comment: I am aware of that. So, I am trying to look for a textbook at the moment..

Comment: The constant may depend on $n$. More generally, a subset $B$ of a locally convex space $X$ is bounded if and only if, for every continuous seminorm $p$ on $X$, there is a constant $C_p\in\mathbb R$ with $p(x)\le C_p$ for all $x\in B$. (The other condition with $C$ independent of the seminorm $\|\cdot\|_n$ is not even a property of the Fréchet space since, e.g., the modified seminorms $|x|_n=n\|x\|_n$ give the same topology but the condition may hold for $\|\cdot\|_n$ but not for $|\cdot|_n$.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One can define boundedness for a general topological vector space $(X, \tau)$ in a more geometric way (independently of any seminorm):

*A set $S \subset X$ is bounded if for every neighborhood $V$ of the origin there is a $\lambda> 0$ such that $S \subset \lambda V$.*

Now, it is easy to show that if $\tau$ is a locally convex topology, induced by the family of seminorms $\{\lVert \cdot \rVert_i\}_{i \in \mathbb{N}}$, then the above is equivalent to requiring that, for every $i \in \mathbb{N}$, $\lVert S \rVert_i = \{\lVert x \rVert_i \; : \; x \in S\}$ is bounded (in $\mathbb{R}$). That's condition (1) in your question.